# Including graphics without bounding box (similar to pstricks' \rput command)

Tags: includegraphics

I have a very specific table that just needs to be this way (even though one might argue that it is not a very TeX kind of way).
The cell in the upper left is supposed to contain a logo and it fits nicely:
[image: table with a sample logo of the correct size]
My question is how to achieve this without using `pstricks`' `\rput` command? If I just include the image, then TeX will reserve some space for it, which I don't want. The padding is fine just the way it is and `\rput` does not seem to appear to pass on any information about a bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}*{6}{l}@{}}
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{3pt}% toprule
% Row 1 ---
    \hspace*{2cm}
&   {Category}
&   \multicolumn{2}{l}{Score}
&   {Result}
&   {Details}
&   More detailed \\
% Row 2 ---
    &&&&&&details
\\[-1.5ex]
% Row 3 ---
%   \includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{scratch.eps}
    \rput(0,0){\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{scratch.eps}}%
    & \small Some Category                  \\[1ex]
    & \small Subcategory
    & \multicolumn{2}{r}{of 30}             \\
\specialrule{.7pt}{4pt}{3pt}% midrule ---
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in a number of ways without the need for [`pstricks`](//ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). Use `\raisebox{<length>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}` to raise `<stuff>` up by `<length>` (negative will lower it). Adding the `[0pt][0pt]` options removes the height/depth of `<stuff>` so it doesn't affect the row height.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  % Option 1
  \scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} c @{} *{6}{l} @{} }
    \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{3pt}% toprule
    % Row 1 ---
        \hspace*{2cm}
    &   Category
    &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{Score}
    &   Result
    &   Details
    &   More detailed \\
    % Row 2 ---
        &&&&&&details
    \\[-1.5ex]
    % Row 3 ---
        \raisebox{-2.35\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{example-image}}
        & \small Some Category                  \\[1ex]
        & \small Subcategory
        & \multicolumn{2}{r}{of 30}             \\
    \specialrule{.7pt}{4pt}{3pt}% midrule ---
  \end{tabular}

  % Option 2
  \scriptsize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} c @{} *{5}{l} @{} }
    \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{3pt}% toprule
    % Row 1 ---
    &   Category
    &   Score
    &   Result
    &   Details
    &   \smash{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}} More detailed \\ details \end{tabular}} \\
    % Row 2 ---
        ~\raisebox{-2.3\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{example-image}}~
        & \small Some Category                  \\
        & \small Subcategory
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{of 30}             \\
    \specialrule{.7pt}{4pt}{3pt}% midrule ---
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Of course, adjust the amount the element is raised/lowered.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the nested tabular too